# getItemInHand() and setHelmet() not working with bukkit, Java

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So basically, my problem is that when I use getItemInHand() and setHelmet(), it returns an error "Change type of item to 'ItemStack'" for both lines. Here is the code where the errors appear:

```
toggle.add(player.getName());
//Do stuff here when enabled.   
player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Enabled!");
ItemStack item = player.getItemInHand();
player.getInventory().setHelmet(item);
```

Please help me, I'd be very grateful.

~ Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you are importing `CraftBukkit` and that the `ItemStack` you import is the `net.minecraft.server.ItemStack`, not `org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack`. If this is the case, change your import and you should be fine.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, but I will tell you that I'm using org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack, It's strange. I want to create this simple plugin but I come across a stupid error like this which is preventing me -_-

Comment: Could you post your entire class please?

Comment: Yeah sure, give me a moment.

Comment: Actually mate, sorry for wasting your time. But I have found the solution. Basically, I imported both the net.minecraft.server.ItemStack AND org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack. This must have been causing complications, I swear my eye sight is going haha! Thanks for the answer anyway, much appreciated.